# Having trouble getting the rest of the numbers in an Array. Java

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, sum, boolean

I'm having trouble in getting the rest of the numbers after I sum up the first 3 elements. This is the question that it asks me: "Write a method that takes an array.  `return true` if the sum of the first three elements in the array is less than the sum of the rest of the elements of the array."

Therefore `5 5 5 5 2 2` should be `false`. Since the first 3 numbers sum are greater than the sum of `5 2 2`. My program returns true for this question and I would appreciate any help.

```
public static boolean sumThree(int [] myArray)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
    {
        sum += myArray[i];
    }
    int sumof3E = myArray[0] + myArray[1] + myArray[2];
    if(sum > sumof3E)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if(sumof3E < sum)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you summing all the elements in the first loop? you shouldn't include the first 3 elements in the first for loop.

Comment: Wow am I dumb LOL. Thank you and the other commenters for the help. This took up a couple hours of my time yesterday!

Comment: you're welcome. see my answer for a shorter way to accomplish your task.

Comment: @IDK also remember that every element starts with index 0

Comment: I guess assignment is about "simple" "classic" `for` loop...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't include the first three elements of the array. Those have to be exclusive of the summation.

Change the for loop control variable to this:

```
for (int i = 3; i < myArray.length; i++) {
      sum += myArray[i];
}
```

Also, you should remove the `else if` block from your code, because it's redundant (the first `if` statement checks for that condition):

```
else if(sumof3E < sum)
{
     return false;
}
```

Alternatively, with the help of java 8 features, you can shorten your code into **one line**:

```
public static boolean sumThree(int [] myArray){
       return Arrays.stream(myArray).limit(3).sum() < Arrays.stream(myArray).skip(3).sum();
}
```

**note** - with the alternative solution you won't get `IndexOutOfBoundsException` even if the array being passed in is empty.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues in your code:

1) You don't verify that the Array even has 3 elements before you index into it, which will potentially cause errors.

2) You're summing the entire array and comparing it to the sum of the first three elements... in your loop try initializing `i = 3` in the loop initialization (assuming the array has at least 4 elements)

Pseudo code:

```
public static boolean sumThree(int [] myArray)
{
  if (myArray.length < 4) { return false; }
  var first = myArray[0] + myArray[1] + myArray[2];
  var rest = 0;
  for(int i = 3; i<myArray.length; i++) {
    rest += myArray[i];
  }
  return first < rest;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the sum loop need to be altered to start from index 2 and else if is not required.

```
public static boolean sumThree(int[] myArray) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 3; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        sum += myArray[i];
    }
    int sumof3E = myArray[0] + myArray[1] + myArray[2];
    if (sum > sumof3E) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: @NatanyaGanesh `i = 2` actually must be `i = 3`

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to keep going through the whole array at a time when first sum becomes less than sum of rest:

```
int sumf3 =0;
int sumRest=0;
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
{
    if (i < 3){
      sumf3 += myArray[i];
    } else {
      sumRest += myArray[i];
    }
    if(sumf3 < sumRest ){
      return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

P.S. and no need to check size of array before loop as well.

Answer (score 0):

for clarity make a two loop then use the conditional operator or known as ternary operator for using thee if..else easily

```
 int sum1=0;
    int sum2=0;


    for(int i=0;i<=2;++i)
    {
        sum1+=myArray[i];
    }
    for(int i=3;i<myArray.length;++i)
    {
        sum2+=myArray[i];
    }
    boolean myBool = (sum1>sum2)?false:true;
    return myBool;
```